# I keep getting an invalid syntax error when trying to run this program in python

Tags: python

It keeps getting stuck on the second def() statement. Beyond that, I need to label the Hourly pay rate, commission pay rate and withholding pay rate as global constants but I keep getting a multiple line statement error. Help?

```
#Define the main function
def main():
    display_message()
    HOURLY_PAY_RATE = 7.50
    COMMISSION_RATE = 0.05
    WITHHOLDING_RATE = 0.25     
    name=input('What is the person\'s name? ')
    sales_amount=input(int('What is the sales amount? '))
    hours_worked=input(int('How many hours did they work? '))
    hourly_pay=hours_worked * HOURLY_PAY_RATE
    commission=sales_amount * COMMISSION_RATE
    gross_pay=hourly_pay + commission
    withholding=gross_pay * WITHHOLDING_RATE
    net_pay=gross_pay - withholding
    display_results()

#Define the display_message function
def display_message():
    print('This program calculates a salesperson\'s pay')
    print('Five values are required to calculate this')
    print('Hourly pay', 'Commission', 'Gross pay', 'Withholding')
    print('and Net pay.')

#Define the display_results function
def display_results():
    print('The hourly pay amount for', name, 'is$', format(hourly_pay, ',.2f'))
    print('The commission amount for', name, 'is$', format(commission, ',.2f'))
    print('The gross pay for', name, 'is$', format(gross_pay, ',.2f'))
    print('The withholding amount for$', name, 'is', format(withholding, ',.2f'))
    print('The net pay for', name, 'is$', format(net_pay, ',.2f'))

#Call the main function
main()
```

Comment: Wlecome to SO.  Please take the time to read [ask] and [mcve].  When asking about code that produces and error/exception, please post the complete traceback.

Comment: This code runs without a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: I get ValueErrors. --> `int('What is the sales amount? ')`

Comment: and `NameError`, but not `SyntaxError`.

Comment: what version of python are you using?

Comment: @KyleHigginson I am using Python version 3.6.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 types of errors in your code:

First:

```
sales_amount=input(int('What is the sales amount? '))
hours_worked=input(int('How many hours did they work? '))
```

the function calls to input and int are in the wrong order. What your code says is, "convert 'What is the sales amount? '" to an integer and make that the input prompt. Cleary, that string cannot be converted to an int type. What you want is:

```
sales_amount=int(input('What is the sales amount? '))
hours_worked=int(input('How many hours did they work? '))
```

Second, you have a scoping error. In display_results() you are making use of the variables name, hourly_pay, commission, gross_pay, withholding, and net_pay. However, those variables only exist within the scope of main. To resolve this you can do one of two things: 1) make them global, or 2) pass them to display_results():

```
display_results(name, hourly_pay, commission, gross_pay, withholding, net_pay)
```

and then refine your def:

```
def display_name(name, hourly_pay, commission, gross_pay, withholding, net_pay):
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a work around for your errors:

```
#Define the main function
def question_one():
    # for python 2 use raw_input
    #numbers = raw_input('What is the person\'s name?\n')
    #for python3 use input
    numbers = input('Persons name, Sales Amount and Hours Worked\n')
    name, sales_amount, hours_worked = numbers.split(',')
    return name, int(sales_amount), int(hours_worked)

#Define the display_message function
def display_message():
    print('This program calculates a salesperson\'s pay')
    print('Five values are required to calculate this')
    print('Hourly pay', 'Commission', 'Gross pay', 'Withholding')
    print('and Net pay.')

#Call the main function
def main():
    display_message()
    HOURLY_PAY_RATE = 7.50
    COMMISSION_RATE = 0.05
    WITHHOLDING_RATE = 0.25
    name, sales_amount, hours_worked = question_one()
    hourly_pay=hours_worked * HOURLY_PAY_RATE
    commission=sales_amount * COMMISSION_RATE
    gross_pay=hourly_pay + commission
    withholding=gross_pay * WITHHOLDING_RATE
    net_pay=gross_pay - withholding
    print('The hourly pay amount for', name, 'is$', format(hourly_pay, ',.2f'))
    print('The commission amount for', name, 'is$', format(commission, ',.2f'))
    print('The gross pay for', name, 'is$', format(gross_pay, ',.2f'))
    print('The withholding amount for$', name, 'is', format(withholding, ',.2f'))
    print('The net pay for', name, 'is$', format(net_pay, ',.2f'))

main()
```

Notice in `question_one()` you have to use different input() functions depending on the version of python you are using. The input for this function would be:

```
`kyle,30,40`
```

It will take all values from the one line and return your calculated data from this. Each value must be separated by a comma. Hope this helps you.